# j_security_check not redirecting to angular with # hash key

Tags: angularjs, jsp, redirect, web.xml, j-security-check

I have a jboss web application with form-based authentication and Angular based client.
Scenario:

1. I go to http://localhost:8082/my-app/#/dashboard, with session timed out
2. It redirects to login page (login.jsp). I enter the username and password, and submit.
3. It sends me to localhost:8080/my-app, **not** http://localhost:8082/my-app/#/dashboard

j_security_check is supposed to return the requested url after successful login. but does it ignore the # suffix?

**login.jsp**

```html
    <form id="loginForm" method="post" action="/my-app/j_security_check">
          <input id="usernameInput" name="j_username" type="hidden" />
           <input id="password" name="j_password" type="password" required="">
           <button type="submit">
                Sign In
              </button>
          </form>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

  <display-name>OpTierUI Application </display-name>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>CSS</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/styles/*</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/fonts/*</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/assets/images/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
      <description>These pages are only accessible by authorized administrators.</description>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/login.jsp?error=error</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/login.jsp?unauthorized=unauthorized</location>
  </error-page>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Browser does not send #hash key or anything after that to server. #hash key is only recognized by browser.